# Why would a flex-item's z-index not work with 'overflow: hidden' in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, overflow

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.blue, .pink {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 1; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="blue">blue</div>
  <div class="pink">pink</div>
</div>
```

`display: flex;` of the wrap element makes the blue element in BFC, so I added `z-index: 1;` to the blue element to make it in top of the pink element. But after I add `overflow: hidden;` to the blue element, its z-index would not work in Safari, instead in Chrome it is totally OK.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You may try adding a minus z-index value for `.pink` and higher value for the `.blue`. Hope this helps. cheers!